# Before Insert and After Update trigger on Same Table Not Working Properly

Tags: mysql

Dear Sir I have a master table tbl_appli_basic_info on this table I created two type of trigger one is after insert and other is before update trigger.I insert first record in master table mean when primary key is one it inserts record in master table Before insert trigger insert record in tbl_appli_basic_info_after_insert which I create separately. Secondly when I update primary key one record say in master table I insert name i.e ab now I update it to abc, after update trigger insert data in another table i.e tbl_appli_basic_info_after_update which I create separately too now issue is that when I update same data twice say name is abc now I changed it abcxzy it not allowed me to update the record My main purpose of using after insert trigger is that it maintain record once it inserts in master table after that I'm not used this table an  after update trigger keep record of a single user how many time update the records with in different rows I am unable to manipulate the code please correct my code I will be great full to you.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tbl_appli_basic_info`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_appli_basic_info` (
  `appli_basic_info_id` int(22) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `apli_reg_no` int(22) NOT NULL,
  `full_name` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`appli_basic_info_id`),
  KEY `apli_reg_no` (`apli_reg_no`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_appli_basic_info_after_insert` (
  `appli_basic_info_id` int(22) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `apli_reg_no` int(22) NOT NULL,
  `full_name` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`appli_basic_info_id`),
  KEY `apli_reg_no` (`apli_reg_no`)
) ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_appli_basic_info_after_update` (
  `appli_basic_info_id` int(22) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `apli_reg_no` int(22) NOT NULL,
  `full_name` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`appli_basic_info_id`)
);

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `trg_appli_basic_info_after_insert`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `trg_appli_basic_info_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `tbl_appli_basic_info` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  -- Insert record into tbl_appli_basic_info_after_insert table
   INSERT INTO tbl_appli_basic_info_after_insert
   ( appli_basic_info_id,
     apli_reg_no,
     full_name)
   VALUES
   ( NEW.appli_basic_info_id,
     NEW.apli_reg_no,
     NEW.full_name
     );

END
$$
DELIMITER ;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `trg_appli_basic_info_before_update`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `trg_appli_basic_info_before_update` BEFORE UPDATE ON `tbl_appli_basic_info` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

   -- Insert record into audit table
   INSERT INTO tbl_appli_basic_info_before_update
   ( appli_basic_info_id,
     apli_reg_no,
     full_name
   )
   VALUES
   ( NEW.appli_basic_info_id,
     NEW.apli_reg_no,
     NEW.full_name

   );

END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your audit table definitions don't make a lot of sense and since you are defining `appli_basic_info_id` int(22) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT Primary key and overwriting this in the triggers thus I would expect duplicate key errors. I would change the table definitions to

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_appli_basic_info_after_insert` (
  id int auto_increment primary key,
  `appli_basic_info_id` int(22) ,
  `apli_reg_no` int(22) NOT NULL,
  `full_name` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  KEY `apli_reg_no` (`apli_reg_no`)
) ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_appli_basic_info_after_update` (
   id int auto_increment primary key,
  `appli_basic_info_id` int(22) NOT NULL ,
  `apli_reg_no` int(22) NOT NULL,
  `full_name` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```